# Bitnami jupyterhub charts on k8s failing due to password authentication failed for user "bn_jupyterhub"

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, bitnami, jupyterhub

I deployed JupyterHub packaged by Bitnami on our GKE k8s cluster under one of our namespaces with the same default values defined in their repo successfully.

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/jupyterhub/#installing-the-chart

However I noticed jupyterhub pod is crashing with Init:CrashLoopBackOff error and logs shows it could not connect to database server.

```
kubectl logs pod/jupyterhub-hub-59cc99bdfb-d4vjx wait-for-db
←[38;5;6m ←[38;5;5m04:24:03.35 ←[0m←[38;5;2mINFO ←[0m ==> Connecting to the PostgreSQL instance jupyterhub-postgresql:5432
←[38;5;6m ←[38;5;5m04:25:03.57 ←[0m←[38;5;1mERROR←[0m ==> Could not connect to the database server
/bin/bash: line 18: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
```

It seems postgressql-0 pod is runnin into authentication error seems to be the cause here. I have not used any changes in the values.yaml file provided in the https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/jupyterhub/values.yaml.

```
kubectl logs jupyterhub-postgresql-0 postgresql
←[38;5;6mpostgresql ←[38;5;5m03:13:30.41 ←[0m
←[38;5;6mpostgresql ←[38;5;5m03:13:30.41 ←[0m←[1mWelcome to the Bitnami postgresql container←[0m
←[38;5;6mpostgresql ←[38;5;5m03:13:30.41 ←[0mSubscribe to project updates by watching ←[1mhttps://github.com/bitnami/containers←[0m
←[38;5;6mpostgresql ←[38;5;5m03:13:30.41 ←[0mSubmit issues and feature requests at ←[1mhttps://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues←[0m
←[38;5;6mpostgresql ←[38;5;5m03:13:30.42 ←[0m
←[38;5;6mpostgresql ←[38;5;5m03:13:30.45 ←[0m←[38;5;2mINFO ←[0m ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL setup **
←[38;5;6mpostgresql ←[38;5;5m03:13:30.46 ←[0m←[38;5;2mINFO ←[0m ==> Validating settings in POSTGRESQL_* env vars..
←[38;5;6mpostgresql ←[38;5;5m03:13:30.47 ←[0m←[38;5;2mINFO ←[0m ==> Loading custom pre-init scripts...
←[38;5;6mpostgresql ←[38;5;5m03:13:30.48 ←[0m←[38;5;2mINFO ←[0m ==> Initializing PostgreSQL database...
←[38;5;6mpostgresql ←[38;5;5m03:13:30.50 ←[0m←[38;5;2mINFO ←[0m ==> pg_hba.conf file not detected. Generating it...
←[38;5;6mpostgresql ←[38;5;5m03:13:30.50 ←[0m←[38;5;2mINFO ←[0m ==> Generating local authentication configuration
←[38;5;6mpostgresql ←[38;5;5m03:13:30.53 ←[0m←[38;5;2mINFO ←[0m ==> Deploying PostgreSQL with persisted data...
←[38;5;6mpostgresql ←[38;5;5m03:13:30.57 ←[0m←[38;5;2mINFO ←[0m ==> Configuring replication parameters
←[38;5;6mpostgresql ←[38;5;5m03:13:30.61 ←[0m←[38;5;2mINFO ←[0m ==> Configuring fsync
←[38;5;6mpostgresql ←[38;5;5m03:13:30.62 ←[0m←[38;5;2mINFO ←[0m ==> Configuring synchronous_replication
←[38;5;6mpostgresql ←[38;5;5m03:13:30.66 ←[0m←[38;5;2mINFO ←[0m ==> Loading custom scripts...
←[38;5;6mpostgresql ←[38;5;5m03:13:30.66 ←[0m←[38;5;2mINFO ←[0m ==> Enabling remote connections
←[38;5;6mpostgresql ←[38;5;5m03:13:30.67 ←[0m←[38;5;2mINFO ←[0m ==> ** PostgreSQL setup finished! **

←[38;5;6mpostgresql ←[38;5;5m03:13:30.69 ←[0m←[38;5;2mINFO ←[0m ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL **
2022-09-01 03:13:30.760 GMT [1] LOG:  pgaudit extension initialized
2022-09-01 03:13:30.765 GMT [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2022-09-01 03:13:30.765 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2022-09-01 03:13:30.766 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2022-09-01 03:13:30.769 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-09-01 03:13:30.775 GMT [91] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-09-01 02:36:41 GMT
2022-09-01 03:13:30.813 GMT [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2022-09-01 03:13:57.645 GMT [116] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "bn_jupyterhub"
2022-09-01 03:13:57.645 GMT [116] DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 1: "host     all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5"
2022-09-01 03:14:02.663 GMT [118] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "bn_jupyterhub"
2022-09-01 03:14:02.663 GMT [118] DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 1: "host     all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5"
2022-09-01 03:14:07.681 GMT [131] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "bn_jupyterhub"
```

This was deployed with the same command **helm install jupyterhub bitnami/jupyterhub**. There were no special instructions or password suppled in the values.yaml file.

What am I missing here? Do I have to specify password values here to make it working? restarting the pod and redeploying the charts seems not helpful.

Any further advises are highly appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thought i'd chip in here...

...This is caused due to deploying/redeploying via a pv/pvc, that doesn't necessarily get deleted - Then when you redeploy if you don't explicitly define a password then the previous pvc gets re-used, it recognises there's a bn_jupyterhub user on the database... And so never updates it.

Workarounds:

1. Specify inside your jupyterhub some override values for values.yaml to explicitly define the bn_jupyterhub password (functional, but clearly insecure).
2. Define a secret prior to deploying, and then use that with the same values.yaml overriding to use that existing secret. That way, the secret doesn't get re-created and you can use forevermore.
3. Define a separate postgres database and configure jupyterhub to use that external database.

Reference: https://docs.bitnami.com/general/how-to/troubleshoot-helm-chart-issues/#persistence-volumes-pvs-retained-from-previous-releases